# Call to undefined method Database\Factories\SupplierFactory::setContainer()

Tags: laravel

From the docs (Laravel 10) Within the DatabaseSeeder class, you may use the call method to execute additional seed classes. Here's my approach:

```
namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Database\Factories\SupplierFactory;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     */
    public function run(): void
    {
        $this->call([
            SupplierFactory::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

```
namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

/**
 * @extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory<\App\Models\Supplier>
 */
class SupplierFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function definition(): array
    {
        return [
            'supplier_id' => fake()->randomLetter(),
            'name' => fake()->name(),
            'address' => fake()->address(),
        ];
    }
}
```

Any ideas why I have problems with the `setContainer()` method above? The syntax looks correct and is consistent with the stock `UserFactory` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a `SupplierSeeder` class where you seed the suppliers. Of course you should already have the `Supplier` Model in addition to the `SupplierFactory`.

Then, call the `SupplierSeeder` class in the `DatabaseSeeder` class.

E.g

```
namespace Database\Seeders;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Models\Supplier;

class SupplierSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run(): void
    {
        Supplier::factory(50)->create();
    }  
}
```

Now you can call the `SupplierSeeder` in your `DatabaseSeeder`

```
namespace Database\Seeders;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     */
    public function run(): void
    {
        $this->call([
            SupplierSeeder::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```